# Creating vector gradiants showing magnitude and direction by taking input of two rasters in QGIS

Tags: raster, qgis-3, grass-gis, vector, direction

I have two binary rasters and I am focusing on pixels having value `1`. Now, I want to know show direction and intensity from which pixels (having value `1`) of one raster is shifted other raster. Basically it is land change study and I want to present it with arrows.

I have tried a tool named *'Gradient Vector from Direction and Length'*, which is not giving desired output because I don't have particular rasters to give input as length and direction.

Attaching raster images here
[image]

Here, I want find red pixels which is one raster, shifts to blue pixels which is another raster.

Comment: If these are binary rasters then how do you determine which red pixel shifted to which blue pixel? I think that the only result you can get will be represented by three categories: which pixels stayed colored (red->blue), which became colored (0 -> blue) and which lost color (red -> 0)

Comment: I wonder if https://grass.osgeo.org/grass-stable/manuals/d.rast.arrow.html may help here...